# Find a chief series for dihedral group $D_{2n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups

The question is : Find a chief series for dihedral group $D_{2n}$. Is each normal subgroup of $C_n$ normal in $D_{2n}$?

Comment: At this level this is not a worth question: what have you tried? Is $\,C_n\;$ the cyclic subgroup of order $\,n\,$ in $\,D_{2n}\,$ ? ...

Comment: Take a look at [the GroupTheory package](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GroupTheory) of Maple 17, especially [the Series command](http://www.maplesoft.com/support/help/Maple/view.aspx?path=GroupTheory%2fSeries).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following example might be a good start: Take the dihedral (not dihydral) group $D_6=\langle a,b \mid a^6=b^2=1,bab^{-1}=a^{-1}\rangle$ and verify that
$$
1 \le \langle a^2 \rangle \le \langle a \rangle \le D_6
$$
is a chief series. For the second part, all subgroups of $C_n$ are normal and of the form $\langle a^d\rangle$ for $d\mid n$. They are also normal in the dihedral group.